# Lightswitch: ASP.Net Runtime error after the deploy

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, runtime-error, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm creating a lightswitch application. This is a web application which is supposed to be deployed on a IIS Server. I'm currently using the VS server.

I'm currently developping an userControl, it was working fine, I was only tunning it(margin, padding, ...), but now when I start it, I got this famous Asp.Net errors:

> > Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on the local server machine, please create a 
>   tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root
>   directory of the current web application. This  tag
>   should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable
>   the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to
>   "Off".

okay, for ASP.NET, I know how to change easily this property, but in a lightswitch application, we don't have access to this web.config.

So anybody knows how is it possibie to have a asp.net runtime error on a page which should only contains the launcher for the silverlight app? Or how to enable this error with a lightswitch application?

Comment: I believe you should be able to access the web.config of a lightswitch application. Have you tried checking the source files, and checked web.config file under the ServerGenerated folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is scaring me, but it seems that sometimes lightswitch is lost and I need to restart visual studio, and without changing anything, it works agains :'(